# TextInputLayout does not animate when inside RecycleView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext, android-support-library

There was a question which was exactly this then got marked as a duplicate. But the proposed "duplicate" does not solve the issue.

When inside a recycleview, I'm using it like (viewholder file):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable name="viewModel" type="my.domain.ui.add.view.CreateMealAddView" />
        <variable name="hint" type="String" />
        <import type="my.domain.base.util.TextValidator" />
    </data>
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/inputText"
            app:validator="@{TextValidator.Rules.NONEMPTY}"
            android:hint="@{hint}"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textColorHint="#DE000000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</layout>
```

Tried setting it dynamically too. The hint displays but the animation does not work when clicking into the EditText. Might this be a focus issue?

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: On what api version you are getting this  ?

Comment: SDK version 27. Testing on Android 8.

Comment: i tested  a similar code on a android 6.0 device and it works fine , it is possibly an Oreo-related issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

In Adapter holder class,

```
yourTextInputLayout = itemView.findViewById( R.id.your_text_input_layout );
```

In Binding class, try,  `yourTextInputLayout.setHint("sample");` instead of `yourEditText.setHint();`

Please make this edit text if you are using edit text

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/inputText"
        app:validator="@{TextValidator.Rules.NONEMPTY}"
        android:hint="@{hint}"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColorHint="#DE000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```